# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS drawAtPoint

Tags: ios, uiimage, exc-bad-access

I occasionally get an exc_bad_access when I call drawAtPoint. Weirdly it does not always occur, generally after this method is called several times. What could be the issue?

```
- (UIImage *)createImage {
  NSString *testString = @"Test";
  UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

  CGSize size = CGSizeMake(256, 256);

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

  [testString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return image;
}
```

Comment: looks ok for me. any more details? whats the error code?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x20)

Comment: Are you running this on a separate thread?

Comment: It's not called on the main thread and could be called by multiple threads.

Comment: I'm not sure, but are string drawing methods thread-safe? Have you tried using `NSAttributedString` instead of `NSString`? Or perhaps try using `drawInRect` instead.